# Defining String Constants in Android Java

Tags: java, android, performance, enums

I am wondering what is the best practice in defining constant strings in Android that are not changed for example I am using an analytics and need to access the information around the entire app.  Should I be using a file like Constants.java where everything is a static string, an enum, or should I be storing that information in the strings.xml

Answer (score 4):

Best practice to create a

> Constants.java

and define your constants like below :

```
public static final int YOUR_CONSTANT_NAME = 14;//for the variables which will not change,
public static int YOUR_CONSTANT_NAME = 14;//which can be changed.
```

**static** - To keep in memory for complete app lifecycle, no repeated initialisation.
**final** - as to keep the system sure that value will not change, once assigned.

In constants file, you can defined constant variables, Prefs name, API Keys, SDK keys etc.

Answer (score 1):

**XML**

- Puting on xml file you will need a `Context` to access it. Then forget it.

**ENUMS**

- Enums aren't the best alternative to consts, why you will need use `toString()`s and casts to some cases. Then forget it also

**Constants.java**

- **The best pratice** is create an `Constants` class where you will put all constants and just use `Constants.MY_CONST` on your calls

Answer (score 0):

You usually would store it in the xml file because that allows you to easily swap between files if you want to change languages

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance there shouldn't be any noticeable advantage in either of those, or at least not to a point to make you choose one or the other without doubts.

I would say:

- *In java code.* When you will **strictly** use those in java code.
- *In strings.xml.* When you think that you will need those both in java code and xml configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable won't change all through the process of your app, set it as for example:

```
Public static final String = "mystring";
```

In a java class say Constants.java.

But if your variable will change like a token in login and logout but you will use it for a specific amount of time, save it in, sharedPrefrences